# Vagrant synced folders structure

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to set up a Django Mezzanine project on Vagrant. I have done the following

1. installed vagrant
2. installed virtualbox
3. `vagrant init`
4. `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32`
5. replaced everything in Vagrantfile with:

   `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
   end`
6. `vagrant up`
7. `vagrant ssh`
8. `sudo apt-get update`
9. `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip`
10. `pip install mezzanine`
11. `mezzanine-project testproject`

But I can't see my files on the host.
I have tried configuring Synced Folders by adding to the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/", "/srv/home/vagrant"
```

To no avail.
I then tried isolating the problem by removing Python from the equation and running the following in the guest SSH instead:

8. `touch foo`

To no avail yet again.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OT, but is there a reason you are not using the Fabric script that ships with Mezzanine? It can and should be customized by the user, but automates everything you are doing. It pains me to watch developers wasting time with work when they could be doing more important things.

Comment: @ken isn't fabric desgined for deployment? Moreover I have only recently begun developing and am already totally overwhelmed with learning stuff that have absolutely nothing to do with code.

Comment: You are deploying, but in your case you are deploying to a Vagrant box rather than a VPS or cloud instance. This is The Right Way. Check out my write-up that covers it: http://bscientific.org/blog/mezzanine-fabric-git-vagrant-joy/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the concept of synced folders back-to-front

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Synced folders make a dir of your *host* visible to the vagrant vm

If you need to see files on the host, you need the files to exist on the host first (and then sync them so the vm can see them too)

Comment: I see ! So I must start/work on my projects on the host and then test them on the VM ?

Comment: PS: I have been through that link, that is where I got the step after 11. It is confusing, because in the Getting Started, they tell you to touch the guest to see it synced on the host, and not vice-versa....

Comment: yes maybe is confusing, but they are demonstrating that the file has been shared _from the host_ yet if you touch it in the vm it still updates on the host.  the advantage of developing on the host is you can use your local editor etc